# Is language/grammar (mathematically?) scientific (like Math)? Is a grammar construct a delineation = to a math formula?

Tags: evolutionary-linguistics, research, grammaticality, linguistic-determinism, literacy

Is language itself scientific? Can the way language is used/abused be scientifically evaluated like a Math problem? Can an English sentence be mathematical?

Are `grammar constructs` defined like (100% equal to?) `math formulas`?

Language and grammar seem to be regarded "like" math, however Math can be reproducably calculated, can the same be said of Language? Another side of language and wording though, is some form of Psychology, meaning Style, Order, and Form, tied to human functions like how we emit/hear/see/feel sound and can remember a paragraph versus a page at a time. Is Math not unique as a Science, for being able to be computed and not require a human being?

Is language and grammar so standardized and prescriptive, made by scientific methods wholly the same as Math follows? A computer can calculate math, but not an English sentence *"yet"*, in terms of Scientific Methods, so how is language graded versus math and is it a fully equivalent determination?

Sympolics of math can be traced and reproduced, anyone can take a formula and make a (the exact) rocket. However, with language and linguicisms there is a nature of supposed mathematical certaintly and exactness, yet there is severe/warring difficulty in society in determining what words mean and how they're said.

We may not know who "invented" a word, any more than who "invented" some maths, but for some reason we all use the same universal Math, unlike language where we *fight* instead. Could it be related to the scientistic scientificness, these "language issues" (I do not hear "math issues" said with the same voice, except maybe in Astronomical Quantum Theory "issues", whereas for language it's always "issues" across the board)?

Even in medical science, there is a requirement for recognition of what we really can prove, blood tests and DNA, versus by-chance knowledge from singular and rare biological phenomena/disorders and problems which have theory but are not given credibility as worthy of funding a *Scientific Experiment*, because there are significant gaps in what can be proven.

That is not to say Linguistics has not tried to formulate why some mouth movement and hearing issue ties exactly to the written form, but is it Rocket Science?

Are rules, standards, repetitions and patterns of how we speak and right so well known enough to be science? Are we saying Science, like Rocket Science?

What efforts have been made to denote the parts of Language that are actually provable by Scientific Formulae and Controlled Experiments, instead of hearsay and references that are trusted as source of the Word. I know that we do not have contact with the universe at the stage of the Big Bang, but we are very careful to make claims about what we know as evidence. I expect to hear NASA say it does not know the Math for some scientific phenomen, yet from English leaders there is almost a confidence game of speaking, because there is not much admittal of what is not actually done by controlled experiment?

My research is having asked [Are rules and standards (patterns and repetitions) of language and grammar sane, scientific, psychological, mentally healthy, good and/or reality-tested?](http://www.quora.com/Mental-Health/Are-rules-and-standards-patterns-and-repetitions-of-language-and-grammar-sane-scientific-psychological-mentally-healthy-good-and-or-reality-tested?share=1) as I study [grammatology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatology) (asking how it is empirical and longitudinal a study, language effects being by certain rules). I apologize for my original edit version being somewhat abstract, and hope I can edit to make sense, err, make math...

When I hear "Science", I was taught to expect evidence and repeatability to a degree that is beyond doubt, which applies to Hard Sciences not Soft Sciences, so which one is Language applied for the average human being. Is a human being who gets/solves a math problem right, the "guaranteed" level, of a human being who gets a word problem correctly?

Should I trust `word order` like a computable `math order`?

Is `deterministic math`, an identical `linguistic determination`?

Or, is the question best asked as if the (English?) language is a Hard Science versus a Soft Science, is comparing/contrasting to Math a valid question/point?

~~Why has language change not had the same stories/experiences as paradigmical math changes?~~

~~Why is counting so important for math, yet not counting for in language? I mean, WordPerfect gives the pretense of Word/Letter Count having a place, but we do not learn that as a form of mathematical precision.~~

I realize there are not any (0) https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math questions.

Linguistics is a science of language, now how is language a science? I mean, should I trust my English teacher as much as my Math teacher to be able to specify letter and word order to a T, with the same rigor and absoluteness that Math *"guarantees"*?

Comment: It's not clear from your question that you have a sound idea of what science is.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Language isn't science any more than matter is. But both of them can be studied scientifically.

Comment: Maybe there is another way to word it, but language is scripted by certain rules and categorization, determined academically and historically? Is that science?

Can we talk about how to develop an understanding of language from its roots that may or may not be scientific?

Comment: Was the work of Aristotle science? Were geocentric theories of the universe science? Science is related to methodology within a given framework of understanding, and to the ways of evolving that framework. It is necessarily historical and academic, whatever the subject, as it can only be a cooperative endeavor in constant evolution. Regarding language, there are often two views: descriptive and prescritive. The former is science and the latter is politics. Science always start with gathering data and examples, then find rules to structure and condense that knowledge. In natural language too.

Comment: Yes that is science evolving! I think you are writing part of the answer. I still wonder what part of writing by nature of itself is science?? Writing is made to be a supreme act, so I think it deserves delineation between creation by study, and habit.

Comment: The study of language—linguistics—is a scientific discipline, subject to the same constraints as other academic disciplines: coherence, consistency, rationality, descriptive adequacy, and conformity to the underlying data. But the actual languages which are the subject of that study are *natural* systems, evolved rather than consciously and rationally designed. They are indeed 'reality-tested', for they have evolved to meet the needs of their speakers to express themselves, to communicate and to lie effectively.

Comment: Mapping and study of language is important scientific research, but science makes mistakes, and replication requires intelligence, from a world where we learn to read and repeat the alphabet and bible. What degree of scientific rigor is part of speech? Can we help language, as a signal system, evolve by analyzing how science has evolved with language, how scientific methods inform language to various points and degrees, how and why? It is important???!!

Comment: The more you write the less clear it is what exactly you're trying to ask. Please try to explain simply what you want to know.

Comment: Grammatology again.

Comment: @curiousdannii Specifying language itself (vs. Linguistics a scientific study of language), in loyalty to specific question wording intent. http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/revisions/8719/4

Comment: @prosodycontext So you're specifically asking whether language, a phenomenon, is scientific? The only times that I can think of when phenomenons are asked whether they're scientific is for paranormal things. "Is telekenesis scientific?" "Is legilimency scientific?" Basically those questions mean "Does this thing actually exist?" Is that the kind of question you're trying to ask?

Comment: @curiousdannii Not asking if lang+sci exists. I ask how letters, grammars, writing etc systems are actually a specifically scientific development origin?? What parts of the origin of language and structure each depends, are rules and expressions designed as specific scientific methods and commands? Empathize maybe, I come from a world where biblical language informs much social construction, so how science stakes language as a supreme system makes me curious! I find our standards to be science based to a point!!, but I do not know if rules of language are exact science as math and programming.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still can't understand you.

Comment: @curiousdannii If language is communication, is communication a science?! I do not understand if language is exactly a scientific system of expression and communication by nature of the "phenomenon"? Classifications by linguistics makes it scientific??  Languages codifications and representations seem to be a long fight between elaborate science and historical holyness. So how does it make sense to crown it as such a scientific etymology?

Comment: I meant to add: Productive linguistic computations can still run with partial science. I wonder if what's being read as ignorance and attack here is related to defending the science of language, whereas I am trying to analyze the exact history and bounds of the scientific process we use to judge language.

Comment: Asking if language or communication is science is like asking if Oxygen is science. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Given that it's been several years since this question was closed, and your edits are lengthy, I recommend just asking it anew.

Comment: @Draconis Good concern, however another perspective is that it can takes years to get good feedback, there is even an https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102412/how-did-i-get-the-excavator-badge https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1287/excavator badge: I've had many q Deleted fully, and not kept Closed (yet Visible) for 7 yrs, which is unique. While my edit is lengthy, it's because I'm verbose, repeating the same concepts in different ways, & not changing meaning. Many of the same mods are still active today, rehashing would honestly terrify me to start from scratch :). Please consider.

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid I can't recommend reopening, because I still don't understand what you're trying to ask. It sounds like you're asking whether _the phenomenon of language_ is science, which is somewhat like asking if frogs are science. Biologists study frogs in a scientific way, and do replicable, falsifiable experiments involving them, so we could call _the study of frogs_ a science. But it doesn't really make sense to ask if _the frogs themselves_ are science. What would that even mean?

Comment: @Draconis @curiousdannii Fair, I get the appeal of asking anew. For the record, I upvoted https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8719/is-language-grammar-mathematically-scientific-like-math#comment20979_8719 and tried to burrow the word correctly. Maybe Science is a loaded term, I mean, which can hurt my question. Is there a way to ask whether the *~~phenomenon~~ concreteness (concrete or what word; Proof?) of language/grammar* is by scientific method? `Is a grammar construct a delineation = to a math formula?`, is another question or can it fit somewhere here? Sorry if it's justme :∫

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand what that means. It still seems somewhat like asking if the proof of frogs is by the scientific methods. Frogs aren't proved like theorems, they're just a thing that exists. Scientific experiments can be done on them, and we can come up with theories and models about them, but we can't prove the frogs themselves. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Draconis I appreciate being scared to talk to me if/when I sound stupid, I give you credit for that given the mod diamond icon suggests some reputation and education beyond me. I am happy to agree I might be missing the correct wording, and sincerely respect you being able to coordinate while I try to change my mind here. So, *given your example*, I do not mind going with `frogs`:) Are "frogs" the basic building blocks/foundations of the symbols in Math AND Lang? So a frog is the +/- signs & a frog is the comma/period? All these frogxamples are same absoluteness/guaranteed proofs/correctness?

Answer (score 3):

Was the work of Aristotle science? Were geocentric theories of the universe science? Science is related to methodology within a given framework of understanding, and to the ways of evolving that framework. It is necessarily historical and academic, whatever the subject, as it can only be a cooperative endeavor in constant evolution. Regarding language, there are often two views: descriptive and prescriptive. The former is science and the latter is politics. Science always start with gathering data and examples, then finding rules to structure and condense that knowledge. In natural language too.

In other words, the answer to your question in unequivocally yes. Linguistics, the study of natural languages, is scientific, even if some would-be contributors may not work scientifically ... as in all sciences. There are certainly fine points that are yet to be mastered, but the technological success of computational linguistics is enough to prove experimentally that phenomena are better and better understood.

Most of the literature on linguistics is equally convincing for someone with scientific maturity and experience. But, as in all sciences, there is still a frontier to be explored and settled.

Though the study of language may have had originally prescriptive aspects, that has probably been true of many other areas of knowledge, that were often contrued as dogma, often also for political and social reasons, pretty much like religion (not to mention an american law, still pending before a state Senate, stating that PI=3). Current works in linguistics is very open to confronting variuos theories of what language is and how it evolved.

Comment: Very grounding starting point! If you may empathize asking, does it seem I am purely ignorant, to question if it is an "unequivocally" scientific language structure? I ask partly as a way to evolve examining social structure, to being as sensitive to sciences as it is dogmas.

Comment: @prosodycontext: Yes, it does seem so. Otherwise you would not continue to ask whether something is "unequivocally scientific". As babou explained very patiently, the phrase means nothing, and can mean nothing, given what science is. I'm afraid that phrases which mean nothing are not infrequent in grammatology, which is neither science nor linguistics, but critical literary theory, pitched at the same level of clarity, coherence, and utility as Chomsky's theoretical works.

Comment: I believe in science to a realistic degree, it is an evolving map. I also believe in scientific errors, to a realistic degree. Language is a map? Zillions of rules and calculations, and science churns through gradually with (careful!!!) examination. Language does not necessarily examine science? I empathize because I feel it helps language to examine science.

Comment: @prosodycontext What are you questionning? Whether the study of language is scientific? Or whether language itself has the right properties, whatever those properties should be according to you.  I tried to make sense of your question, and answer. But I fear that I failed.

Comment: @babou I don't fear your questioning me about scientific methods. You help asking. Just letting us ask if language is scientific requires a lot of work! Science is still learning to analyze how to call things (and to agree!)!! I feel scientificness of language needs elaboration, and this answer helps examine and make sense of the historical timeline.

Answer (score -3):

Language itself may try and work to be scientific, but while linguistics examines scientificness, language itself grew through many systems aside from science itself.

> "Language itself is culture, not science.  Grammar is a science because there are established rules and constructions; however, it is not an exact science as there are too many variables, and the rules even change at times." -mwestwood, college teacher, commenting about ["Why do we regard the study of language as a science?"](http://www.enotes.com/homework-help/language-400350) might be part of the answer?

Language scientificness is a worthy study, with linguistics ready to help analyze. In a sense, science is learning language, and language is learning science too.